# How to send floats as paramters in Django 2.0 using path()?

Tags: python, django, url, celery

I have developed a Python script with arguments. 
It has functions to perform the differents operations depending on the arguments received.
Now I am trying to pass that arguments or parameters through the API. 
I am using `path()` new function of Django 2.0 (specifically this is the version I am using: 2.2.9) 
What is the way that passing floats in url in Django?
It is working with integers but not with float.

What is the best ways to pass float? Do you convert to HEX for example?

Example using GET to point to the API anf fire a task:

Not working:
http://x.x.x.x:8000/proveedores/api/pruebascelery/buy/0/1.1287
(last parameter is a float)

works with integer:
http://x.x.x.x:8000/proveedores/api/pruebascelery/buy/0/2

Django: (urls.py)

```py
path('pruebascelery/<slug:post_id>/<slug:post_id2>/<slug:post_id3>', lanzador_task_start)
```

Django: (views.py)

```
def lanzador_task_start(request, post_id, post_id2, post_id3):
    comando = "python /home/developer/venvpruebas/recibirparametros.py " + str(post_id) +str(" ")+ 
str(post_id2)+str(" ")+ str(post_id3)
    lanzar.delay(comando)
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Done</h1')
```

python side:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import struct


def RecibirParametros(recibir_todo):

    print("Received: ", recibir_todo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    recibir_todo = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
    #[1] test1
    #[2] test2
    #[3] test3
    #--------------------------------------------------------------
    RecibirParametros(recibir_todo)
```

Comment: Have a look at [register_convert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#django.urls.register_converter) to learn how to add a custom float converter or use `re_path()` to use a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters) for customize url parameters.

in converts.py

```
class FloatUrlParameterConverter:
    regex = '[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return float(value)

    def to_url(self, value):
        return str(value)
```

in urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

from . import converters, views

register_converter(converters.FloatUrlParameterConverter, 'float')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('pruebascelery/<float:post_id>/<float:post_id1>/...', views.year_archive),
    ...
]
```

For alternative methods:

You can use regular expressions inside urls.py directly with `re_path` function like that:

```
re_path(r'^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+$', blog_articles)
```

Also, you can retrieve your parameters from url as query params.
Example url for this:

```
http://x.x.x.x:8000/proveedores/api/pruebascelery/buy/?post_id=1.5&post_id2=2.5...
```

Comment: I used path converter and works perfecty. Thank you.